# Adding and removing values from ConcurrentHashMap while iterating over it

Tags: java, collections, concurrency, java-8, java-stream

I have this code:

```
private ConcurrentMap<String, Integer> myMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

 @Scheduled(fixedDelay = 600_000)
 public void foo(){     
    myMap.values().stream().
                filter(predicate()).
                forEach(this::remove);
}

public void insert(String str, Integer value){
   myMap.put(str, value);
}
```

What would happen if while iterating over this map - someone will put a new value in it or remove an existing value from it?

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: @BuhakeSindi - not sure I understand what you are asking

Comment: What I am saying is have you created an test case that matches your scenario.

Comment: @BuhakeSindi - Oh... I'm not sure how I can compose such test

Comment: It’s not clear what `this::remove` is supposed to do. That implies that there has to be a `remove` method in *your* class which receives a value to do *what*? Iterate over the map again, to remove the value? Consider `myMap.values().removeIf(predicate());` instead…

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The documentation for [`ConcurrentHashMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html) has some details about the behavior. First we look at what [`ConcurrentHashMap.values()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html#values--) does:

> Returns a `Collection` view of the values contained in this map...
>
> **The view's iterators and spliterators are *weakly consistent*.**
>
> The view's `spliterator` reports **`Spliterator.CONCURRENT`** and `Spliterator.NONNULL`.

What's interesting are the terms ["weakly consistent"](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html#Weakly) and [`Spliterator.CONCURRENT`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Spliterator.html#CONCURRENT), where the former is described as:

> Most concurrent Collection implementations (including most Queues) also differ from the usual `java.util` conventions in that their Iterators and Spliterators provide *weakly consistent* rather than fast-fail traversal:
>
> > - they may proceed concurrently with other operations
> > - they will never throw `ConcurrentModificationException`
> > - they are guaranteed to traverse elements as they existed upon construction exactly once, and may (but are not guaranteed to) reflect any modifications subsequent to construction.

and [`Spliterator.CONCURRENT`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Spliterator.html#CONCURRENT) is described as:

> Characteristic value signifying that the element source may be safely concurrently modified (allowing additions, replacements, and/or removals) by multiple threads without external synchronization. If so, the Spliterator is expected to have a documented policy concerning the impact of modifications during traversal.

From all these documentations, and being consistent with the concurrency model of the `ConcurrentHashMap`, it means that the stream pipeline is completely thread-safe and will traverse the elements as they existed upon the creation of the iterator.

Comment: Thanks! Following @BuhakeSindi's question, I tried to compose a unit test that uses several threads that adds and removes elements from this map (a few for insertion and a few for removal) - and during that time, I've ran my foo() method and indeed - no harm was done...